# How to use PageProducer with HTML File

Tags: html, delphi

I am sending emails normally. But I am trying to create a procedure to send emails replacing <#TAGS> with PageProducer. The procedure reads my ClientDataSet, and sends one email for each registry, substituting <#EMAIL>. I am  using HTMLFile property to load the file HTML.

Problem: When I try to send email without PageProducer, works fine. But with PageProducer I am failing. I want to send without save a new file html.

Some one can provide an example how can I do that?

Comment: What is your problem? Using PageProducer or retrieving the generated Content from PageProducer? Please add some code to show what you have tried so far

Comment: `begin
    PageProducer1.HTMLFile := ('page.html');
    // Save New Page HTML //
    SendEmail;
end`

My problem is between save new html... How can I do this? After this, I will loop this procedure to do this for every registry in DataSet.

Comment: Add this to the question and a little bit more code

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer:

> PageProducer is just a component for producing HTML content by
>   replacing some tags with your specified content. It has no feature for
>   sending emails.
>
> To send email in Delphi 7, you can use IdSMTP component from Indy
>   Clients tab in Components Palette. As it is clear from its name, this
>   component uses SMTP protocol for sending emails.
>
> In your case, you should first generate HTML content using either
>   PageProducer or any other method, and then pass the HTML content to
>   IdSMTP to be sent as an email.
>
> To send an email in both plain text and HTML format you should use
>   multi-part message. You can refer to Indy help for TIdMessage class.

Source: [How to send an email using PageProducer in Delphi 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273119/how-to-send-an-email-using-pageproducer-in-delphi-7)